# Hive query in oozie coordinator

Tags: hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I running 10 hive scripts using oozie coordinator, it is getting stuck in one of the script in reduce stage at same percentage without any error, the scripts are simple insert statements and I tested them on command line they just work fine, how do I debug this?

Comment: Have u check the user from which u are using oozie have all the permissions to the HDFS folder in which hive insert statement is inserting data.

Comment: It was a skew data issue and as i am using hive 0.9 the skew optimization join doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It was data skew issue, 80% of the data was mapped to single key. Once we updated to Hive 10, skew optimization join resolved the issue.